# Qt Python Access content of a tab in QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtabwidget

My app is a basic list of QLineEdit where users enter values and click on "generate" to create a config file for a drone.

```
<widget class="QLineEdit" name="namespace">
   <property name="text">
      <string>Drone1</string>
   </property>
</widget>
```

if I do :

```
self.namespace.text()
```

I receive the value of this field.

Now, we want to create one config file for many drones, so I used QTabWidget to create a tab for each drone in my qtapp and I just don't understand how to select a tab, extract all my values, pass to next tab, extract all values...

something like this :

```
for x in tabWidget.count():
   do_something(tabWidget.tab[x].namespace.text())

#or

for tab in tabWidget:
   do_something(tab.namespace.text())
```

I'm not an expert of Qt and I did not find a lot oh things on the web so I think I don't have the good reflexion on this problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use `tabWidget.setIndex(i)` to set the current tab by its index `i` in the QTabWidget (use `tabWidget.count()` to figure out how many tabs are there). Or you can also use `tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(tab)` if you have stored a reference to one of the tab's widgets in `tab`. Docs are here (it's for PySide2, but it's basically the same as PyQt5): https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTabWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget.setCurrentWidget

Comment: If by "select" you meant "access", use [`widget(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#widget): `do_something(tabWidget.widget(x).namespace.text())`

Comment: I just found it thank you

Comment: @q7frkz for future reference, please be more careful with terminology: "select a tab" and "access its contents" are two **very** different things.

Comment: @musicamante ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok
I found it, it's in the documentation and I did not see it

```
for x in self.tabWidget.count()
   do_something(self.tabWidget.widget(x).namespace.text())
```